# need help regarding the output of the following code with explanation if possible

Tags: c

```
char c = 250;
c += 8;
```

What value does c have after the above statements are executed? (Give your answer as a decimal integer.)

i have tried the value 258,3.
tip : write out addition in binary.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What's a *decimal integer*?

Comment: Have you tried doing that?

Comment: By the way, the outcome of that addition *really* depends on compiler and target, since `char` can be either signed or unsigned (it's implementation specific). And signed overflow leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 2):

The type `char` can be signed or unsigned - that depends on the implementation. Assuming 8-bit `char` the range of values that can be held are

> Signed: -128 to 127
>
> Unsigned: 0 to 255

The code starts with

```
char c = 250;
```

which is out of the permissible range of a signed `char` and what happens when you assign that value to a signed `char` is *undefined*. So lets assume that the `char` is unsigned and now

```
char c = 250;
```

is a valid assignment. So let's do the addition in binary as you were advised

```
  Binary   Decimal

 11111010    250
 00001000      8
 --------    ---
100000010    ???
```

The sum overflows 8 bits, and with unsigned values, it is truncated to 8 bits (modulo 256).

```
 00000010      2
```

So the result is either `2` (unsigned) or *undefined* (signed).

Answer (score 0):

For an unsigned char you have a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 255.

Therefore if you add 250 to 8 you get 2.
This happens because when you have a value of 255 all the bits in that byte are 1. Incrementing the least significant bit will overflow all the way "to the end" and you are left with all bits at 0.

If you need a better understanding of this I recommend these:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number

Comment: They have a signed char though

Comment: The standard does not guarantee that `char` will always be signed; it doesn't even guarantee that `char` will *only* have 8 bits.

Comment: It guarantees a char is always 1 byte. A byte can be different sizes. So you can do the calculations based on how many bits in your byte. This scales perfectly fine